# Calling validate function on button and getting the result (true/false)

Tags: jquery-validate, form-submit, validation

I am trying to do following task:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){

     var success =  $("#myFrm").validate();

      if (success == true)      {
            // post form through ajax
      }
      else{
            // set focus on first field
      }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) method:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){

     var success =  $("#myFrm").valid();

      if (success == true)      {
            // post form through ajax
      }
      else{
            // set focus on first field
      }

});
```

This assumes, of course, that you've configured jQuery validate on the form in question (using `$("#myFrm").validate()`).